# How to inject variables into a Terraform JSON template for a Logic App

Tags: terraform

I have an exported template of a logic app built in Azure.  The JSON file has information such as the subscriptionid which will vary depending upon environment.  How do I use a variable instead of the literal value, as an example:

```
"defaultValue": "/subscriptions/**328974123908741329180713290587125**/resourceGroups/rg-management/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-5"
```

being replaced with something such as:

```
"defaultValue": "/subscriptions/**var.subscription**/resourceGroups/rg-management/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-5"
```

I'm not sure of two things.  First, how to actually use this to create the logic app, and second my JSON template, exported from the Azure Portal, doesn't contain any information about the connections to the storage accounts, so not sure how to work this one out.  The JSON follows my updated module, it's fairly large.

Here's my updated terraform module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.env, azurerm.mgmt]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "storage_replication" {
  name                = "logic-app-storage-replication-${var.environment_name}-${var.resource_location}"
  location            = var.resource_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

templatefile("${path.module}/LogicAppStorageReplicationTemplate.json", }"
  {
    subscription = var.subscription_id,
    resource_group = var.resource_group,
    resource_location = var.resource_location,
    container = var.container
  }
)
```

Here is the exported JSON template with the variables added in, key vault I'll deal with later:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_ReplicateStorage_name": {
            "defaultValue": "ReplicateStorage",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azureblob_4_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/${subscription}/resourceGroups/${resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-4",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azureblob_5_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/${subscription}/resourceGroups/${resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-5",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_ReplicateStorage_name')]",
            "location": "${resource_location}",
            "identity": {
                "principalId": "#############",
                "tenantId": "################",
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)_2": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 10
                            },
                            "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 10
                            },
                            "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                                "queries": {
                                    "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                                    "folderId": "/${container}",
                                    "maxFileCount": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": "@body('Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)')",
                                "headers": {
                                    "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob_1']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                                "queries": {
                                    "folderPath": "@{replace(body('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)')?['Path'], body('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)')?['Name'], '')}",
                                    "name": "@body('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)')?['Name']",
                                    "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                }
                            },
                            "runtimeConfiguration": {
                                "contentTransfer": {
                                    "transferMode": "Chunked"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)": {
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/GetFileByPath",
                                "queries": {
                                    "path": "@triggerBody()?['Path']",
                                    "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": {
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                                "queries": {
                                    "inferContentType": true,
                                    "path": "@body('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)')?['Path']",
                                    "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "azureblob": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_azureblob_4_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "azureblob-4",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/${subscription}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${resource_location}/managedApis/azureblob"
                            },
                            "azureblob_1": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_azureblob_5_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "azureblob-5",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/${subscription}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${resource_location}/managedApis/azureblob"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've read through that doc and I'm still a bit confused, Terraform is not my strong suit.  I also forgot that the key/value pairs come from an Azure key vault.  So I'm not sure how to piece these together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) function.

First, in your .json file, replace the id with an [interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html) expression, like this:

```
"defaultValue": "/subscriptions/${subscription}/resourceGroups/rg-management/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-5"
```

Then in Terraform, you would generate the final JSON like this:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/my_template.json", { 
  subscription = "328974123908741329180713290587125" 
})
```

You mentioned you want the value to come from an [Azure Key Vault secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_secret), so that would look like this:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/my_template.json", { 
  subscription = azurerm_key_vault_secret.my_secret.value
})
```

Of course the result of the `templatefile()` function call needs to be assigned to a local variable, a resource property, or a module input, but without seeing any of your code it's difficult to give a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, here's the module so far, not much to look at:

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.env, azurerm.mgmt]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "storagereplication" {
  name                = "StorageReplication"
  location            = var.resource_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit the comment but it didn't work:
Thank you for your help, here's the module so far, not much to look at:

`terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.env, azurerm.mgmt]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "storagereplication" {
  name                = "StorageReplication"
  location            = var.resource_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}`

Comment: The Azure Vault ID is data.azurerm_key_vault.mgmt_infra.id.  I'm unfortunately inheriting this project so there's a lot of issues with finding half of the stuff.

Comment: You should have enough to go by now. If you are still stuck, post all your code in your original question (by editing the question), including your attempt at using the `templatefile()` function, formatted so it is readable,.

Comment: I apologize for readability, I'm not sure what happened there.  I think I'm good, totally agree and again thank you so much for your help.  I have one last question.  Is it possible to store the map inside of another file instead of calling it inline.  The template json file will have a good number of variables in it.

Comment: You can have as many .tf files in the same folder as you want. You define variables in Terraform in a [locals block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html). So you could have a separate file like `template_vars.tf` with a `locals` block that defines that map.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to set a local variable to provide the name of the vault.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my StorageAccountReplication.tf file so it now looks like below:

Note, trying to get it to display properly.

Comment: Please don't post so much code in comments. Edit your original question to post an update if you need to.

Comment: Sorry about that, original post has been updated.